# How to Change the Deployment Order of WSO2 Enterprise Integrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

In my ESB project, I have a lot of Data Services and Proxy Services. And  Proxy Services call Data Services in sequences.
In versions 5.x.x, DSS and ESB are separated, but from EI 6.x.x they combine with each other. The problem is when I start EI, Proxy Services are deployed before than Data Services. EI cannot find called Data Services, so Proxy Services cannot be deployed.

I guest I have to fix the deployment order, so that Data Services start before Proxy Services. How I can do that?

Here is one of failed deployed Proxy Services:

> TID: [-1234] [] [2017-11-03 08:14:35,121]  INFO
>   {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService} -  Building Axis service
>   for Proxy service : COMPLAIN_px
>   {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService}
>       TID: [-1234] [] [2017-11-03 08:14:35,122] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService} -  Error reading from
>   wsdl URI {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService}
>       java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>         at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>         at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>         at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
>         at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
>         at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
>         at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:242)
>         at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
>         at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
>         at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
>         at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
>         at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
>         at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
>         at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
>         at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
>         at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfigUtils.getOMElementFromURL(SynapseConfigUtils.java:316)
>         at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService.buildAxisService(ProxyService.java:318)
>         at org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController.deployProxyServices(Axis2SynapseController.java:701)
>         at org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController.createSynapseEnvironment(Axis2SynapseController.java:390)
>         at org.apache.synapse.ServerManager.start(ServerManager.java:182)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.initESB(ServiceBusInitializer.java:468)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:206)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.persistence.service.InboundEndpointPersistenceServiceDSComponent.activate(InboundEndpointPersistenceServiceDSComponent.java:49)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:514)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:94)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       TID: [-1234] [] [2017-11-03 08:14:35,124]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController} -  The proxy service
>   COMPLAIN_px cannot be deployed - Continue in Proxy Service fail-safe
>   mode. {org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController}

Comment: Sounds a bit similar to this: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3064 Seems to me that the issue is known but WSO2 is reluctant to fix it.

Comment: According to the CAPP deployment archetecture, the EI could not determine the other services in the CAPP. Hence, unable to control the order. Have you tries the order dataservises and proxies are defined in the artifacts.xml file inside the CAPP. I think you can control the behavior using this.

Comment: Thank you @vinok! I'll try your suggestion and let you know the result.

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of architecture, it is not a good practice to place proxies and services providers (DSS) in the same node.

The recommendation is to separate into different nodes, where in one case the WSO2 EI or ESB is a container of services (Data Services); in another node providing proxies services.

With this approach you will not have the incidence that you describe.

I hope it helps you;

Comment: I agree that it isn't very good architecture. I just migrated from ESB 5.x and I would like to use the advantage of DSS - ESB combination in one node to reduce latency.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this. Unzip the CAPP. Change the order the dependancies are defined(artifacts) in the artifacts.xml to the order you want. Archive it again and deploy. Check the magic!

Comment: Thank you, @vinok! I tried your way and it resolved my problem. I hope my question and your answer can be useful for somebody else.